# How to reduce render time?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image]
This single frame took about 2 Hours to render. I plan on making an animation with this scene, so something needs to be done about that. I have all lights (The two Lamps and a sun) set to **one** bounce. Yes, I am using volumetrics, however I have them set up so it should be minimal;

[image]

I'm suspecting its polygons, but I'm not entirely sure. If anyone could check out my file and see if theres a genuine problem with it or if its just some setting I have switched.

I'm rendering with a GTX 1060 6GB.

[Heres the .BLEND. It's 500mb by the way (I dont know why it is)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzgDIjhDOu6EM012TWlHZzI0QnM)

Comment: have you tried [this](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/)? It's a little bit older but it should still help.

Comment: @theoretisch yea I have tried all of those

Comment: Maybe you just have to use a renderfarm. Or you try to add the volumentrics after the rendering with the compositor.

Comment: Have you tried baking?  Also I would fake the god rays in the compositor.

Comment: @PGmath How would I bake? And how would I fake god rays in the compositor? I'm unfamilier with this

Comment: Here are 2 intro courses: Baking: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles/ Compositor sun beams node: http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/572-tutorial-light-rays-using-the-sun-beams-node.html

Comment: Before looking at the comments, I thought...bake...remove volumetrics. Like PGmath said, that is definitely the direction to go. On the other hand, (this will be far less effective) you could do some other tricks to reduce noise with decreased samples. I would suggest making the volumetrics only visible to the camera by unchecking everything else in the object settings, and make sure there are very few bounces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well for one you vastly overrepresented the geometry of simple objects. See for example your arm chair:

[image: crazy number of polygons]

There is no need to have this many polygons. I don't even think you are using smooth shading and it looks smooth just because there are so many polygons. It looks like this with solid shading:

[image: In solid mode there isn't much detail]

But guess what happens when I add a decimate modifier and set the reduction factor to 30%? It looks the same but has way less polygons. With the kind of displacement you're doing, you should really be using microdisplacements with texture maps, and normal mapping instead of insane polygon counts. For the chair you could get by with just normal mapping which is  computationally way cheaper than displacement mapping but gives similar results when the geometry is not dramatic or on the silhouette as seen from the camera.

Regarding render times, there are lots of optimizations you can do but unless you reduce the polygons the BVH tree will be huge which will make everything else slower. You probably don't need 2500 samples on an animation. If you are playing back at 30 frames/second you can accept a tiny bit more noise and you won't notice much because it only lasts for 1/30 a second and the noise on each frame is unique. First reduce the polycounts though, then worry about render optimizations. A relatively unoptimized scene of that complexity should take about 3-10 minutes to render on a GTX 10XX card with those noise levels you have now.

Comment: I thought it was sometime along these lines.. But jesus I did what you said to everything in my scene with geometry (A single cushion on the couch had ~150,000 faces) and blender runs way smoother now. Haven't done a render yet, i'm gonna try what others said about "Baking" textures. Kudos

Comment: As a slightly related side note I think this is how much of the CG community developed its ridiculous fetish for "low poly" art. There is this mentality that if you can get by with less, you should, and it was probably was born out of a distaste for long render times and then some just took it too far and thus we have low poly mania.

Comment: Just as with one of your previous questions about the [number of samples](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68891/what-amount-of-samples-to-use) Use only the amount of vertices that allows you to have the shape you need. Every vertex,Edge, Face you add will use additional resources. The challenge is trying to keep things to the bare minimum (even if you get a render farm of supercomputers)